# Is a Cauchy sequence - preserving (continuous) function is (uniformly) continuous?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, continuity, uniform-continuity, cauchy-sequences

Let $(X,d)$ and $(Y,\rho)$ be metric spaces and $f:X\to Y$ be a function and suppose for any Cauchy sequence $(a_n)$ in $X$, $(f(a_n))$ is a Cauchy sequence in $Y$.

Is $f$ continuous?

Let $f$ be continuous, is it uniformly continuous?

Comment: A good tame example of a counterexample to the second claim is $f(x)=x^2$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Answers are [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy-continuous_function). And more can be found [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27901/does-cauchy-continuity-imply-uniform-continuity-no).

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207559/continuous-functions-and-cauchy-sequences

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes if $f$ sends Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences then it is continuous:

Let $x\in X$. Assume for the sake of contradiction that $f$ is not continuous at $x$. Then exists an $\epsilon>0$ and a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $X$ such that $a_n\rightarrow x$ but $\rho(f(a_n),f(x))>\epsilon$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

To finish the proof consider the sequence $$
b_n=
\begin{cases}
a_n, \ n\text{ even},\\
\\
x, \ n\text{ odd}.
\end{cases}
$$
The sequence $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is Cauchy but $(f(b_n))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ it isn't.

Comment: If a sequence diverges, then is it necessarily non-Cauchy?

Comment: @VikrantDesai This is true only when the metric space $X$ is [complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space).

Comment: I didn't understand the latter part of your proof. I mean why $ (f(b_n))_{n \in \Bbb N} $ is not Cauchy?

Comment: @VikrantDesai The sequence $(f(b_n))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is not Cauchy because $\rho(f(b_{2n}),f(b_{2n-1}))=\rho(f(a_{2n}),f(x))>\epsilon$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: Got you now. Nice proof.

Comment: Just for the curiosity I want to ask that why we took a specific Cauchy sequence? It should be true for all Cauchy sequences right?

Comment: For which one do you mean specific. The $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ or the $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$? If you mean the $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ then the answer is No is not true for all the Cauchy sequences. For example if you take a constant sequence then is not true. The $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is not specific is general.

Comment: I meant $ (b_n)_{n \in \Bbb N} $. I said so because we want to prove that "If $f$ sends Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences then $f$ is continuous." so we proved it's contrapositive which is "If $f$ is not continuous then it doesn't send any Cauchy sequence to a Cauchy sequence". Is my thinking right?

Comment: No the contrapositive is "If $f$ is not continuous then it is not true that 'sends Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences'" or equivalently "If $f$ is not continuous then there is at least one Cauchy sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that $(f(a_n))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is not a Cauchy sequence"

Comment: Now all of my doubts have been cleared. :)

Comment: Under what conditions can one tell 

: Cauchy Continuous $\implies$ Uniformly Continuous?

Comment: I thing you are wrong because you should use the axiom of choice to construct $a_{n}$ by constructing a new sequence in the codomain of $f$.

Answer (score 5):

No it is not necessary to uniformly continuous. Take function $ f(x) =x^2 $ on real line. note that if you take any cauchy sequence  then it is contained  in some closed bounded interval and there function is uniformly continuous so image sequence must cauchy. But function is not uniformly continuous on whole real line.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f:(0,1)\to \mathbb R$, defined by $f(x)=1/x$. $f$ is continuous. Sequence $1/n$ is Cauchy in $(0,1)$, while $f(1/n)=n$ is not a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: You take the question wrong!