# Cauchy Continuous function is continuous??

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity, cauchy-sequences

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces.Let $f:X\to Y$ be function which is Cauchy Continuous.Show that $f$ is continuous.

Cauchy Continuity:Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces, and let $f$ be a function from $X$ to $Y$. Then $f$ is Cauchy-continuous if and only if, given any Cauchy sequence $<x_n>$ in X, the sequence $<f(x_n)>$  is a Cauchy sequence in Y.

I am planning to use sequential definition of Continuity but I am unable to produce a neat proof without completeness.Give me some idea!

Comment: see this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344452/is-a-cauchy-sequence-preserving-continuous-function-is-uniformly-continuou?rq=1

Comment: @WLOG nice proof.Thank you!